# Failsafe way to load Shared Object

Tags: c, glib

I am curently using the GLib `g_module` functions to load some shared objects during runtime.

The basic way I use is the following:

1. Call `g_module_open` to get the module
2. After that, call `g_module_make_resident`
3. Load Symbols by using `g_module_symbol`

As I am using this as a basic way to add plugin compatability, I am interested if there is a good way to make sure that even if the loaded module has a bug (like memory corruption (`malloc`/`free`)) the main application can just 'catch' this error without crashing everything?

I realy do not want you to write any code, I am just interested if there is a good way to achive this...

Comment: shared libraries are loaded into process address space. Thus no, you cannot truly isolate your process from bugs in shared library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Severin mentioned, there isn't really anything you can do easily.  That said, you do have a few options:

The first thing you might want to consider is using something like libpeas, which allows you to load plugins in languages with non-C linkage (JavaScript, Python, etc.).  Many of these languages provide much more safety than C, so if you're trying to protect against programmer error (as opposed to malicious modules) this could be a good way to go.

The other relatively straightforward way to accomplish this would be to run each plugin in a separate process.  You can communicate over D-Bus, pipes, etc.  One advantage of this approach is that some modules can have less permissions; if you have a program which interacts with hardware that may need root permissions, but your UI could still run as an unprivileged user.  Telepathy is an example of this sort of architecture.